# kdenlive crashes on export

Tags: video, crash, kdenlive

Everytime I press "Render -> Start Rendering" kdenlive crashes without any error message. Anyone experienced the same issue?

It does not happen with some newly setup projects, but with a big one I've been working on for a while

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Have you tried running `kdenlive` from a terminal? Does it not print an error message there when you attempt rendering?

Comment: Did you try changing the destination of the export?

Comment: @rlee827 Yeah, it did not give an error message when crashing.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yes, did not work though.
Fixed it by getting the latest version of Kdenlive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix it by using the **latest version of Kdenlive.** The latest version in the Appstore was 15, but Kdenlive 18 is provided with a .Appimage at https://kdenlive.org/en/download/ .

With the new version the crash did not happen yet.

Thanks for all participants, though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of crashing while rendering, and I tried a little solution to fix it

It's just by **rescaling images** before editing the video

So if you're working on a **HD video** resolution and you insert a **4K image** it will be acceptable at editing but will crash at the rendering

So you need just to **scale down** the images before inserting them on your project

May this be helpful for everyone

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you look for, but in my case, the rendering itself crashed (the program was still running) until I did the following:

1. Go to 'Settings' > 'Configure Kdenlive'
2. In the section 'Playback' switch on the option 'Use GPU processing'

Hope it helps ^^